# Android 360 Panorama ImageView with HotSpots

Tags: android, android-imageview, 360-panorama

I am trying to achieve something like in this website (https://app.immoviewer.com/portal/tour/1110531) in my android app. I am using this library to show my 360 images (https://github.com/lespinsideg/SimplePanorama). But I am unable to add hot spots in the image. I just want to change the picture when a user clicks on a hot spot. Please guide me. Thanks.

```
<com.lespinside.simplepanorama.view.SphericalView
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:id="@+id/spherical_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:yaw="0"
        app:pitch="5"
        app:zoomFactor="0.6"
        app:enableZoom="false"
        app:rotationSensibility="130"/>
```

Comment: Hi did you got output?

Comment: Any output did you get using hotspots in panorama view in android?

Comment: hey, the above library didn't work so i added a javascript lib in my assets and then loaded it inside webview in my app.

Comment: Thank you shaw, We are done...

Comment: @Shaw can you share a code sample that shows how you achieved what you wanted using the Webview. I am trying to achieve the same behaviour but I am kinda lost here. Thank you